# Encryption JNI crashed during stress testing

Tags: java, cryptography, java-native-interface

In my project, the crypto(AES, Blowfish) algorithms are implemented in C as a shared library, and invoked by Java as JNI interface. There is no memory leak of the shared library by using Valgrind. However,during stress testing on Java side, JVM breaks down **occasionally**, and it's very difficult to locate the cause. The error log indicates GCthread crashed, and I'm going to look into GC.

Please give me some hints how to solve such kind of issue. Thank you very much.

Some info from error log:

Current thread (0x00007fc1e3002800):  **GCTaskThread** [stack: 0x000070000021d000,0x000070000031d000] [id=9219]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x00007fc104000280

Comment: "breaks down" is a very vague term. You probably have stack trace, or something. One of the causes of your crash could be related to multithreaded access to some shared data structures. Does your stress test use many parallel threads?

Comment: Thanks for reply. The test program is single threaded. "break-down" means crash; though I can get stack trace, it contains too much information and is hard to identify the code cause crash.     The test program uses following code for test:  while(1){ aes_cipher_encrpyt(input,output...)  // JNI here }

Comment: So, it's more like repetitive test (do you have randomized input?) rather than stress-tests. One of the causes of occasional failures with random data may be that (a) the data is not well-formed, or (b) you hit some corner case where your parser fails. Does the same occasional crash happen when you run a tight loop with exactly same data every cycle?

Comment: Hi @AlexCohn,  the error log indicates GC thread crashed(see edited original post). I mainly use C and see that it would be safe if mallc()/free() is used appropriately, yet JVM is out of our control. The oracle doc http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15059/crash.htm provides some suggestions to solve GC crash. I believe GC should be extremely robust; either the C code or the JVM setting caused the crash.

Comment: @AlexCohn We used data in stack as input which can be considered as random, and the trickiest thing is it's hard to reproduce the crash - sometimes it runs 2 hours and sometimes it runs 10 times (for the AES function); also, error log points to different code that cause the error, e.g., SetByteArrayRegion(). Can you give me a roadmap to solve this issue?  I'm a babie in Java. Many thanks.

Comment: Any way you can compare the address space mapping of one of `SEGV`'d processes to one that doesn't fail?  Are there any trends over your test?  For example, a series of 64k anonymous memory mappings that slowly grow as the test runs?  Also, JNI is *extremely* unforgiving, so make sure you check *every* JNI call for success.  Don't assume anything works - not even lookups for classes that you'd think *must* be accessible because otherwise your JNI library implementation that's making the lookup call wouldn't even have been loaded.

Comment: You should try to comment OUT some C code, in a attempt to find where you misuse JNI. How big is your C code?

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that our C code has memory pitfalls found by Valgrind. It's highly recommended to strictly test memory footprints of C code using profiling tools, e.g., Valgrind.